# Como colocar um elemento antes de outro com jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como fazer pra por um determinado HTML antes de uma outra div? tentei usando `prepend` mas ele poe no inicio dentro da div mas eu quero que coloque acima/antes e fora dela, usando `prepend` ela fica assim:

```
<div class="pai"><div>FILHO</div></div>
```

mas o correto e necessário para mim seria assim:

```
<div>FILHO</div><div class="pai"></div>
```

é possível com que código?

Comment: E qual é o HTML inicial?

Comment: @Sergio o trabalho teria que ser feito em cima da div `$(".pai")...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para retirares a div com HTML `FILHO` de dentro da div `.pai` e colocar a mesma *antes* da div `.pai` podes fazer assim:

HTML inicial:

```
<div class="pai">
    <div>FILHO</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var pai = $('.pai');
var filho = pai.find('div'); // vai buscar a div que tem HTML filho
filho.insertBefore(pai); // inserir div que tem HTML filho antes da div .pai
```

HTML final:

```
<div>FILHO</div>
<div class="pai"></div>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6717y46x/

Comment: Nao sabia dessa função.. Mas se por acaso eu estiver a receber o html e ele nao existir ainda na página eu faria como? Tipo eu recebendo um html de um ajax e quero coloca-lo a frente da `.pai`.. Da mesma forma que foi feito..

Comment: @user3163662 coloca esse HTML numa variável como aqui `var filho = pai.find('div');` e o resto é igual. Se vier de ajax podes por exemplo fazer `var filho = 'string com html aqui';` e usar o resto igual.